# Xamarin Forms - Wait for async method to complete before continuing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms application, I have code that opens a popup page (using the Rg Popups plugin) which executes a call to my API that inserts some data on the database.
I need the async call for the popup to open to wait until the popup page's task finishes then execute another async call which updates a ListView in the current view.

However, the popup's async task does not wait until the popup has finished working to continue to the next task, which means the view isn't updated

Here's the code in question:

```
 bool jobTask = await CloseCurOpenJob();
                 
if (jobTask == true)
{
  await FillDocuments();
}
```

```
 await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new JobClosePopupPage(Base.activeJobId));
 return true;
```

```
private async Task<string> FillDocuments()
        {
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                if (jobid > 0)
                {
                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(myApiUri);
                    var DocumentsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentHeader>>(response);
                    Documents = new ObservableCollection<DocumentHeader>((IEnumerable<DocumentHeader>)DocumentsList);

                    DocumentCount = Documents.Count();
                    DocumentSubtotal = Documents.Sum(instance => instance.TotalQuantity);
                }
               
                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
}
```

And here's the code in the popup page's ViewModel

```
private async Task<bool> CloseJob(int jobid)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(myAPIUri);
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await CheckGetOpenJob();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Base.applicationTitle, responseString, "OK");
                    return false;
                }


              

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Base.applicationTitle, e.Message, "OK");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
                
            }
        }
```

I have tried using Task.Run and Task.Delay but the result is still the same - the FillDocuments method runs after the popup has been shown, not after it has been dismissed.

Comment: I only have one CloseCurOpenJob, not two - I don't know what you mean

Comment: Sorry, typos on my part. You call CloseCurOpenJob but list the method `CloseJob`; they also have different signatures. Am I missing something or is there an error in your question/code?

Comment: Oh! CloseJob is an entirely different method - it's the task that runs on the PopupPage's ViewModel. CloseCurOpenJob runs on the main page's ViewModel. I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: Did you try the code I provided? Does it work correctly?

Comment: I haven't managed to try it yet - currently occupied by another task (no pun intended). I will update you accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Task.Wait()` and `Task.Result` will make the program wait for the async task method competed.

If the `CloseCurOpenJob()` is like `public async Task<bool> CloseCurOpenJob(){}` You can try the following code:

```
// Both are applicable to simple Tasks:
bool jobTask = CloseCurOpenJob().Result;
```

or

```
Task<bool> result = CloseCurOpenJob();
result.Wait();
bool jobTask = result.Result;
```

According to your description, you want update the popup when it show. But you sayed that the popup will not show when you used the .Wait() method.

Generally speaking, it shouldn't happen. But you can try to use the Thread.Sleep() such as:

```
bool jobTask = await CloseCurOpenJob();
Thread.Sleep(1000); //make the thread to wait for 1s and the async task usually completes in 1s          
if (jobTask == true)
{
  await FillDocuments();
}
```

But this way seems not elegant, you can post the code about the `CloseCurOpenJob()` method. In addition, if the `CloseCurOpenJob()` is `public async bool CloseCurOpenJob()`, you can make the thread wait without the await. Such as

```
bool jobTask = CloseCurOpenJob();
```

Comment: If I wanted the thread to stop until the "jobTask" completed, would I use jobTask.Wait()?

Comment: You need declare a Task<bool> to get the value. I had edited my answer. @F.Bill

Comment: It didn't work - in fact, it breaks the application as the popup will not even show!

Comment: I had edited the answer and show all the ways I can provided. You can have a try.@F.Bill

Comment: I had tried Task.Delay() and it seemed to only work when the data sent to the API was small - whenever the data was larger, resulting in a longer time needed for the API to process it, the delay would not be enough. So I cannot use a fixed delay time. I think I know what's going on and long story short, there's no way for this to work as intended and I probably need to change my workflow!

Comment: I have added an answer of my own, please check it

Comment: According to your description, you want make the async method run as a synchronous method. So you can try to delete the await.@F.Bill

Comment: Please check the answer I have added - I think I have figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share something I've figured out:

The problem was not in the code, but the flow of it.
Namely, I needed one page to dismiss a popup while ANOTHER page was working.

The solution I think I found - it has not been tested - is as follows:

Show the popup
Do the processing in the main page's thread after showing the popup - as it's asynchronous, the code will continue to the task.
Dismiss the popup in the main page's code (using the PopAllPopup method of the Rg plugin).

So...

```
bool jobTask = await CloseCurOpenJob();
                 
    if (jobTask == true)
    {
      await FillDocuments();
    }
```

Would become

```
await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new JobClosePopupPage(Base.activeJobId));
bool jobTask = MethodThatProcessesTheData().Result;
await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync();
```

I think this is how it's supposed to go...